# prevent sharepoint deletion items by user creator

Tags: list, sharepoint, delete-row

How can I prevent users from deleting sharepoint calendar list item, if the logged user is not the organizer or creator of the item? i need to prevent deletion items only if the logged user is the item creator

Comment: Hm that sounds confusing: the first sentence contradicts with the second one. Do you want the creator to be able to delete the items he created, or the opposite?

Comment: What is the version of your SharePoint? Server/on-premise or Online?

Comment: @jleture Online

Comment: @Nikolay i want to prevent users from deleting a SharePoint calendar list item, specifically when the logged-in user is not the item's organizer or creator. i want to limit item deletion exclusively to the user who originally created it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, i created a new permission where people can only create items and view them, but cannot edit or delete. then i made a flow taht is triggered when an item is created.

then, i assigned edit and delete permissions in the new item for the creator, their subordinates, and their manager using the "get manager" and "get subordinates" functions.

[image]

[image]

the images are in spanish, i'm costarican...:)

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint Server, it will be easy to develop and deploy an `Event Receiver` with the method `ItemDeleting` to prevent non-author deletion. With SharePoint Online, there is also something called `Remote Event Receiver` but it requires to host custom code on Azure. https://abdulazizfarooqi.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/sharepoint-online-remote-event-receiver-item-deleting-using-provider-hosted-app/

For your use case, there is something **easier**: item-level permission. Do you think about it? However, it will prevent edit **and** delete, and not only delete.

1. Open the **list settings** of your Events list
2. Click on **Advanced settings**
3. **Item-level Permissions**: check "Create items and edit that were created by the user"

[image: item level permission]

Now, anyone with contribute role can create event but only the original author can edit or delete this event. Please note that non-author can see the Edit and Delete button **but** when pressing the button an unauthorized page will be displayed.

[image: unauthorized page]